# While updating the table it is freezing the application

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nolock

I have an update query which runs every hour. When it runs it freezes the system and nobody can work. How to fix this issue

### My query is :

```
update  SL
set TrsID=U.TrsID
from ST (nolock) as T
join SL as P on T.TrsID=P.TrsID
join ST (nolock) as U on U.TrsUnionID=T.TrsUnionID
        and U.LotID=T.LotID and U.TrsID<>T.TrsID
where T.TrsID>195171640
and U.TrsTypeDesc2=' (PENDING)'
```

---

I used (nolock) still it freezes. What to do

Comment: Can you please provide database structure, data and desired output.

Comment: I am getting the desired output what i wanted, my concern is can we do something to prevent locking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per microsoft 'No lock' is deprecated ,so you can't expect the desired result using that keyword .Read more on the topic in these links [Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(v=sql.90).aspx) and [Link2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.90).aspx).

[image]

If your problem is because of the resource blocking ,then use transaction with appropriate Isolation Level.